# How to read Cloudsat data in HDF4 format in R

Tags: r

I have seen the previous post to open .hdf file in stackoverflow using the gdalUtils,raster using Modis data. I have tried all but my file is not opening. Please help or suggest anything to open in R. By the way my files are in hdf4 format. While trying with already given code i got following error and warning given in [error.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS0L2.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by first converting it to .h5 with the help of a h4 to h5 converter and then open the .h5 file in R by a package rhdf5. This is available here source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")